# Implicit functions and partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-function

I am trying to solve the following exercise about implicit functions and their partial derivatives:

If $u=x+y+z$, $v=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $w=x^3+y^3+z^3$ prove that:
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\left(\frac{yz}{\left(x-y\right)\left(x-z\right)}\right)\:;\:\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}=\left(\frac{1}{3\left(x-z\right)\left(y-z\right)}\right)$$

I am not sure of the procedure I should follow. What I have done with previous exercises of this kind does not seem to work for this one.

Comment: Have you tried using the implicit function theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem

Comment: That actually helped. Thank you for your suggestion.